# Laravel 404 status code для SPA react приложения

Tags: reactjs, laravel, http, react-router

Я делаю spa приложение на react+laravel, в котором на laravel написано api.
И я хочу сделать для SEO статус коды (404, например).

Кратко: как в laravel+react настроить 404 http ошибку без ssr для несуществующих роутов?

1. Например, у меня есть страница с офисом: `/iffices/1` - на ней с помощью react-router я отображаю компоненент страницы. В этом компоненте я отправляю запрос на сервер `api/offices/1`. И полученную информацию я вывожу на странице.
   Но, если такого офиса нет, запрос к api возвращает 404 ошибку, но страница всё равно загружается со статус кодом 200. Как указать браузеру, что такой страницы не должно быть (404)?
2. Если я запрашиваю вообще не существующую страницу, например `/fsdsdf`, то в react-router я отображаю Page404 компонент. Как помечать такие страницы тоже, как 404? Ниже представлен код:

```html
<BrowserRouter>
            <Layout>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
                    <Route path="/rent/:officeCrmId" element={<RentOfficePage/>}/>
                    <Route path="/sell/:officeCrmId" element={<SellOfficePage/>}/>

                    <Route path='*' element={<Page404 />}/>
                </Routes>
            </Layout>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

```js
/**
 * Redirect all routes (except .md files) to ReactController that renders react
 */
Route::get('/{path?}', [ReactController::class, 'index'])
    ->where('path', '.*')
    ->name('home')
;
```

Comment: Без SSR никак. У Вас страница должна отдать 404 уже при обращении, а на момент загрузки сервер не знает ничего о прогружаемом контенте, и только как js прогрузится, только тогда уже что-то происходит и выдается страничка.

Comment: Ну и всё ещё пока большое сомнение в том, есть ли жизнь SEO с SPA